# c# clickonce events?

Tags: c#, clickonce

Is there an event fired straight after or during a clickonce update that I can overload or subscribe to?

Answer (score 5):

You can subscribe to the following events

- CheckForUpdateCompleted -    Occurs when CheckForUpdateAsync has completed.
- CheckForUpdateProgressChanged -  Occurs when a progress update is available on a CheckForUpdateAsync call.
- DownloadFileGroupCompleted - Occurs on the main application thread when a file download is complete.
- DownloadFileGroupProgressChanged -    Occurs when status information is available on a file download operation initiated by a call to DownloadFileGroupAsync.
- UpdateCompleted -    Occurs when ClickOnce has finished upgrading the application as the result of a call to UpdateAsync.
- UpdateProgressChanged -  Occurs when ClickOnce has new status information for an update operation initiated by calling the UpdateAsync method.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment_events.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.Deployment.Application APIs for custom upgrades. It will do exactly what you want

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.aspx